# Flutter Adding Account with AccountManager?

Tags: flutter, accountmanager

### Query

I want to adding account with AccountManager in Flutter.

I have googled but I found in Android not in Flutter; I found flutter package:
https://pub.dev/packages/account_manager_plugin

this package get all account but never to add new account.

any body help me...

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no available plugin that has all the features of Android’s [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager). You’ll either have to dive into its [source](https://github.com/Yeikel200/account_manager_plugin) to jumpstart and create your own plugin, wait for one to be available, or integrate your own [Android-specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

Comment: Still waiting !